# Succinctly get just one object property from an array of objects where another property matches a search

Tags: javascript, arrays

I searched on this site and read several articles about reduce, map, and filter, but I think I just don't know what to search for. I'm running several queries on an API, where first I run search #1 for XYZ, then with the results from Search #1, I run Search #2 with one of the properties from the array of results that Search #1 gets. Basically it goes down a chain of promises, getting more details from the API as it goes. I can make it work with a cheat / workaround but it feels there must be a more ES6 succinct way to do this.

```
async function LoopOverArrayAndRunSearch(json) {

   for await (let item of json) {
      searchNumber1(item.property1).then(data => {

     // Find the items where the search name matches the result name
     let nameMatchExactlyArray = data.filter(apiItem => apiItem.name === item.property1);

    // get the id from the first value of the array

    console.log(nameMatchExactlyArray[0].id);    // this feels sloppy!
    let matchingID = nameMatchExactlyArray[0].id;

    // run search2 using the matchingID
    searchNumber2(matchingID).then ....


 }    
}
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey Could be a dupe but could also someone else who doesn't know what to search

Comment: That's the point of duplicates. If someone finds your question (by a search that matches your key words and phrases), they get a link to the duplicate, and the answer, without having the answer duplicated in a million places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .find instead of .filter:

```
let foundId = (data.find(apiItem => apiItem.name === item.property1)).id;
```